# Unable to set text dynamically in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have this simple HTML/JS file that I'm working with. When I click the generate button, I should the output of the `normalize` function shown as text on the screen, but that's not happening. Can someone help me figure out why the `p` element is not being updated?

```js
function normalize(str) {
  output = str.toLowerCase();
  return output;
}

function generate() {
  input = normalize(document.getElementById("input").value);
  document.getElementById("output").textContents = input;
}
```

```html
<div id="input_div">
  <input type="text" size="25" id="input">
  <input type="button" value="Generate" id="gen" onclick="generate()">
</div>
<p id="output"></p>
```

Comment: You should get in the habit of declaring your variables properly using [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) or [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let). e.g `let input = ...`.

Comment: If you want more than one line, you can split on comma for example: `const normalize = (str) => str.toLowerCase().split(",").join('<br/>')` and use innerHTML instead of textContent

Comment: Or use a [textarea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTextAreaElement) and instead of textContent use [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) which will preserve the line endings.

Answer (score -1):

A typo.

The property you're looking for is `textContent` not `textContents`.

Comment: Thanks. Now, what should I do if I want to have multi-line output in the `p` spot?

Comment: Please do not answer typo-type questions.

Answer (score -1):

You can either use "textContent".

```
   document.getElementById("output").textContent = input;
```

OR "innerHTML"

```
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = input;
```

Comment: Please do not answer typo-type questions. Add a relevant comment and if you have the rep, vote to close